# SOAP version in Envelope from code generated by WSDL

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm working on a solution with a service generated by WSDL. When I call the service I get a Bad Request-Error. I've enabled tracing and the message sent has the following envelope:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
```

When I try to use cURL I get an error saying "InputStream does not represent a valid SOAP 1.1 Message" and of course works perfectly fine when I change xmlns:s to use SOAP version 1.1.

In the WSDL the binding is:

```
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
```

which as, from what I've found, SOAP 1.1.

How can I modify the WSDL or the generated code to send the message with correct SOAP version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All there was to it was to add textMessageEncoding in the binding

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
```